# how to use ng-repeats in ng-repeat with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I am trying to do following but it's not working.

```
<div ng-repeat="a in ar">
    <div ng-repeat="b in br">
        <div ng-if="a.num == b.num">{{b.type}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do array objectives comparing same values
arrays is

```
ar = [ {num:1, str:"a"}, {num:2, str:"b"}, {num:3, str:"c"} ];
br = [ {num:3, type:"text"}, {num:5, type:"number"}, {num:8, type:"date"}];
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Looks like it works to me: http://plnkr.co/edit/0zvAcsWUSEMpdchLBhH1?p=preview

Comment: Do you have an error or something ? What is displayed ? You could provide us with a JsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, its creating the outside divs, you can see it if you add a reference to the a items:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in ar">
    {{a.str}}
    <div ng-repeat="b in br">
        <div ng-if="a.num == b.num">
            {{b.type}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```